# webpack error cant resolve './src'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack, command-line-interface

I am new to webpack. I am learning react and building environment for it using webpack.

I have webpack-config.js

```
var path = require('path');


module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: './script.js',
    output: 
    {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        filename: 'transpiled.js'
    },
    module: 
    {
        loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            query:
            {
                presets: ['es2015','react']
            }
        }
        ]
    }
}
```

and script.js

```
    import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
    <h1>Hello world</h1>    
    document.getElementByIdName('first')
);
```

and index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="first"></div>
    <script src="transpiled.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

in Pakage.json file I have written

```
"scripts": {
    "it": "webpack-dev-server --hot" 
  },
```

But when i run the npm with ***"npm run it"***, it shows me the error of

WARNING in configuration
The 'mode' option has not been set. Set 'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for this environment.
ERROR in multi -dev-derver/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src
Module not found: Error : Cant resolve './src' in D:\React Js \LearnReact' @multi -dev-derver/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src
i ?wdm?: failed to Compile.

Please help me i am really stuck and want to know the solution.

Comment: have you created a `src` folder?

Comment: Did you load the webpack config file? If I remember correctly, you have to specify that in your npm scripts or use the default name `webpack.config.js`. Take a look at the docs https://webpack.js.org/configuration/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add pass the `--config` option to `webpack-dev-server`:

`webpack-dev-server --config path/to/webpack.config.js`

Also set your mode to `development` in your base config, you can overwrite it later when you do a production build.

Also ensure that your `./script.js` file is in the root of your project, i.e next to your `package.json` since this file path is relative to the `npm` script execution.

Based on this configuration --> `path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')` all your built assets will end up in a `src` folder in the root of your project, assuming that is where your `webpack.config.js` file is (this path is relative to your config file). The actual folder will only be generated in `production`, in `development` assets are stored in memory.

You might also want to set a `publicPath`:

```
output: {
  ...
  publicPath: '/'
}
```

I would also recommend using the `html-webpack-plugin` since this can resolve the correct paths to your js file for you.

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

...
plugins: [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    filename: 'index.html', // name of file that will be outputted to 'src' when built
    template: // path to your html file relative to config
    inject: true
  })
]
```

Then you don't have to include the path to your script, so your html file would look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="first"></div>
</body>
</html>
```